# How let netcat wait for response from client side?

Tags: netcat

I have two commands which I use in console to send and read data, but my problem is that they don't wait for an answer I would need.

My current setup is:

```
printf "msg\n" | nc localhost 34567  // client sending msg command
nc -l 34567                          // server side
nc localhost 34567                   // client reading msg command
printf "answer\n" | nc -l 34567      // server side
```

I would like the second client command to wait `@timeout` seconds in which the server have time to respond, but the first command also should somehow make sure it send data and the server got it.

Perhaps I should look at error messages and look for them in loop?

Comment: There is a timeout option in `netcat` which you could try adding `-w`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{
cat <<EOF ; sleep 1;
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Connection: close

EOF
} | nc www.google.com 80
```